# audio tag play not working in mobile when even javascript call

Tags: javascript, jquery, audio

*My HTML*

```
<audio id="myAudio" style="display:none">
    <source src="audio/heart.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"/>
    Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>
```

## My JavasScript

```js
$("#play").click(function(){
        $("#myAudio").get(0).currentTime = 0;
        $("#myAudio").get(0).play();
    });
```

**Not Working In My Phone. Please Help me!**

Comment: which browser is it? Also Autoplay is not allowed in modern broswsers, you ned to add audiocontext

Comment: Google Chrome Browser

Comment: https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/09/autoplay-policy-changes#webaudio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may need to add audiocontext on window load

```
window.onload = function() {
  var context = new AudioContext();
  // Setup all nodes
  ...
}
```

and need to resume context before play

```
context.resume().then(() => {
     $("#myAudio").get(0).currentTime = 0;
    $("#myAudio").get(0).play();
    console.log('Playback resumed successfully');
  });
```

Comment: thank you very much. Although it does not solve my problem

Answer (score 0):

Try editing your jQuery Code as below!

```
$("#play").click(function(){
        $('#myAudio').trigger("play");
});
```

Same as for pausing audio, use

```
$('#myAudio').trigger("pause");
```

Comment: thank you very much. Although it does not solve my problem